# Quotation of code on meta sites differs from the main ones

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting, per-site-meta, blockquote

When I add code in quote on main sites it looks fine:

> [image: main]

But if I do same on meta, result is significantly differs:

> [image: meta]

As you can see, only the text is highlighted, not the whole line.

Pictures above are from SO, but seems it applies for all meta sites. Unless there can be a different color for code highlighting.

Comment: Looks like the `<pre>` which gives code blocks the background color on main sites is actually the same color as the quote, and only the `<code>` element within that has a different color on metas (except GD where [it's all the same color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcF30.png)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed now:

> [image: meta code quote]